# Effective way to check a list of string to extract certain words

Tags: python

I am trying to check 20,000 list of strings and compare with certain words/phrases to classify them properly into 3 categories.

Here is a sample list of strings:

```
  sample = ["the empty bus behind me", "the facility is close", "my order was canceled", "no empty on site", "no bus for me to move"]
```

So I want to check if a string has:

```
    "empty" and "bus" and "empty" then emptyCount += 1

    "order canceled" or "canceled" then cancelcount += 1

    "empty" or "site" or "no empty on site" then site += 1
```

I have a code that does this, but I don't think it's more effective, and might actually be missing some key points. Is there any piece of advice on how to go about it?

```
    site = 0
    cancel = 0
    empty = 0
    count = 0
    for i in sample:
        if "empty" and "bus" and "empty" in i:
           emptycount += 1
        elif "order canceled" or "canceled":
           cancelcount += 1
        elif "empty" or "site" or "no empty on site" 
           site += 1

        else:
           count += 1
```

Comment: Can you share the code you currently are using?

Comment: "I have a code that does this" - please show it and explain how it's not effective enough

Comment: if you want to make it faster you can use Threads

Comment: Okay, I will edit and input my code now/.. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use count, if you want how many string in that list just use `len(sample)`

Comment: If you are not restricted to built-in modules only, I suggest you use `pandas` for this. The results will be clear and more efficient.

Comment: @HenryYik can you guide me through how to use pandas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to extract.

All you need to do is search and increment count

```
sample = ["the empty bus behind me", "the facility is close", "my order was canceled", "no empty on site", "no bus for me to move"]

empty_counter = 0
for string_item in sample:
    if 'empty' in string_item:
        empty_counter += 1

print(empty_counter)
```

If it's efficiency you're looking for then I would suggest using pandas. This will increase your efficiency 100x depending on the size of data, and it's a data science package meaning it can handle millions of data very fast.

```
#import pandas package.
import pandas as pd

sample = ["the empty bus behind me", "the facility is close", "my order was canceled", "no empty on site", "no bus for me to move"]

# create a pandas series
sr = pd.Series(sample) 

#search for match and store results 
results = sr.str.match(pat = '(empty)&(bus)' )

#gives total number of matching items
print(results.shape[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this, just thinking if there's any way to go efficient way to go about it. Thanks

Comment: Added another efficient way of searching for you.